# Find the control of dynamically added partial view span content in JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

We have partial view  View1 as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem)
{
    <div id = "partialview-content>
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Name, new {id = "name", @class = "name-class"})
                    // Additional controls
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr class="rowSpace">
                <td>Label Text</td>
                 <td>
                    <span id="business-key-id">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.BusinessKey)
                    </span>
                </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
    }
</div>
```

When user clicks on Add New Item in Main View, partial view will be added dynamically.

When user enters some text in name textbox in the dynamically added partial view, BusinessKey DisplayFor should be updated dynamically.

So I added below code in the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".name-class").live('keyup', function (event) {

        var name1 = $("#name1").val();
        var name2 = $("#name2").val();

        var name = $(this).val();

        (".business-key-id").html(trustName + ' ' + seriesName + ' ' + trancheName); 
    });    
});
```

Doing this code is updating the business-key-id of all the dynamically added partial views. How can I get the control of the business-key specific to the keydown event control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is selecting all elements with the class name business-key-id

```
$(".business-key-id").html(...
```

Change the selector to select only the next element

```
$(".name-class").on(...
  $(this).next('.business-key-id').html(...
```

Note `.live` has been depreciated - you should use `.on`

**Edit**

Based on OP's revised html, the selector to choose the coresponding `business-key-id` should be

```
$(this).closest('table').find('.business-key-id).html(...
```

And change the html to use the `class` attribute, not `id` attribute (duplicate ID's are invalid html)

```
<span class="business-key-id">
  @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.BusinessKey)
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the inputs. I missed some nesting in my previous question. I updated the same in my question now. I replaced the .live to use .on in JQuery and then added the .next('tr.rowSpace td span.business-key-id').html('...'); This time, nothing is getting updated in the UI. So my JQuery selector is wrong. Can you please correct me where exactly I am going wrong.

Comment: OK, you need to change the selector to match the revised html. I will update answer shortly